# How to combine 3 grayscale images to colour?

Tags: java, image-processing, grayscale, imaging

I have one method to combine 3 greyscale images to one colour image which is done by using `getRed()`, `getGreen()` and `getBlue()` in Java, for each individual input image and then applying the colour to the output image which works quite well. Im looking to find other methods for doing this however.
It doesnt have to be accurate in terms of sea being blue, etc. but it needs to be coloured in a way that different areas of the 'map' can be differentiated.
Ive been looking into ways of doing this but unfortunately havent actually managed to find an alternative way of doing it, im looking to use something apart from the `getRGB()` values.

Im not looking for anyone to code for me, just to give me some pointers on what to look for.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to define what you mean by combining 3 grayscale images. All methods of combination are going to deal with using getRed, green and blue in some way

Comment: Are you trying to ask about additional color spaces?

Like:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lab_color_space 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSV_color_space 
These can be useful in image processing.. If you are I'm not sure SO is the place to ask

Comment: Well theyre landsat 7 images taken at different wavelengths and I want to combine them to make a single false colour image. By combine I just mean using the pixels values of each to create a single image, I did it first by using the red pixel values from input 1, green pixel values from image 2 and blue pixel values from image 3 and putting them all together which created a fairly accurate colour image. Im just now looking for different ways to do that.

Comment: Maybe using another colorspace (_e.g._ YCbCr) the resulting image can be more suggestive than in RGB.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment here is critical:  "but it needs to be coloured in a way that different areas of the 'map' can be differentiated. Ive been looking into ways of doing this but unfortunately havent actually managed to find an alternative way of doing it"

What did you do with the other 4 images - or "channels".  Usually, when doing color space mapping one has 3 channels and one converts to another 3 channel color space.  In your case you have 7 channels, and you want to put all that information into 3 channels?  It all depends on what you are viewing.  Hyperspectral imagery would be a good place to start to see containers for storing imagery data with more than 3 channels.

You can convert to a different colorspace as others have suggested or perform any other transformation.  It sounds like though in order to differentiate different parts of the image, you will need some post processing.  This will depend on your transformation.